# How to replace a string with another and with a different colour in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, reactjs

I have a string mapped from an array and I have used a regexp to return particular text. I want this particular text to have a different color when it is rendered. However the current approach fails as it wont let me just set the style of the string in pure javascript. Is there a way around fixing this so the replace can work with the new text as a different colour.

Ideally, the final outcome would look like this

```
@user This is text
```

Whereby `@user` is blue and the rest is black

```
{this.state.dataReplies.map((n, i) => {
            var re = /@(\S+)\b/g;
            let oldstr = n.description.match(re);
            console.log(oldstr);
            let newstr = oldstr.style.colour = "#0066ff";
            let str = n.description.replace(oldstr, newstr);
    return (
      <p>{str}</p>
    );
})}
```

Comment: You can't style a plain string. Instead just wrap the selected stuff in a `<span/>` which has the desired styling.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/gadawag/pen/NWPXezz

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jayce444 for the solution:

```
{this.state.dataReplies.map((n, i) => {
            var re = /@(\S+)\b/g;
            let oldstr = n.description.match(re);
            let str = n.description.replace(oldstr, "");
    return (
      <p> <span style={{color: "#0066ff"}}>{oldstr}</span> {str}</p>
    );
})}
```